# Futures and callbacks for changing value to variable

Tags: scala, callback, future

I'm currently struggling a bit with the logic of Future callbacks in scala.
I'm trying to get a method that should do the following:

1. Completes with value x if x completes successfully
2. Completes with value y if x fails and finally
3. Completes with the exception that failed y if x and y fails.

Here is my code, which for some reason does not work:

```
def eitherF(x: Future[Int], y: Future[Int]): Future[Int] = {
  var ret : Future[Int] = x
  ret onComplete {
    case Success(i) => 
    case Failure(t) => ret = ret.flatMap(e => y)
  }
  ret
}
```

When ret is returned it always has the value of x, it's like the onComplete block is completely ignored.
 How can I modify the value of ret depending on the result you get from x and y?

Comment: Do you want to return the exception or throw the exception?

Comment: In case 3 I want to return the same Future y that caused the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Future.fallbackTo`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@fallbackTo[U%3E:T](that:scala.concurrent.Future[U]):scala.concurrent.Future[U]) and [`Future.recoverWith`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recoverWith[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,scala.concurrent.Future[U]])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]):

```
def eitherF(x: Future[Int], y: Future[Int]): Future[Int] = {
  x.recoverWith {
    case _: Exception => y
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem with:  
`ret.recoverWith({ case e: ArithmeticException => y })`  
since the exception thrown in this perticular application would always be of that type.  
 Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Yuval I'm not sure if `fallbackTo(y)` is even needed here

Comment: @slouc You're right. `recoverWith` will take care of the fallback.